# Is there a way to speed up TinyMCE placeholder load time?

Tags: django-tinymce

I have recently upgraded TinyMCE to the latest version and the editor itself loads almost immediately.  The issue I'm having is that the placeholder value takes up to 3-4 seconds to appear.  I using the latest tinymce-django version and have gone through all of the docs and can't find a way to speed up the appearance of the placeholder.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?  I've attempted to turn on the compressor but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Because the interface loads right away it's hard for me to tell if the compressor is in fact turned on and if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to never fail....but after posting this question...I played with my init file....as it was giving me an error in the developer console....

I would up commenting out the line that was trying to reference my CSS file in the init and this seemed to speed up the load time even more.  Now the placeholder loads instantly...This is the line that I commented out...

```
  content_css: [
    '//assets/css/mystyle.css'],
```

I don't appear to need this setting for now based on how I've used the source files to change my config appearance.  I had an extra slash in front of the library and that seemed to be what was causing the placeholder load time delay.  On to the next....